# Syzygies of projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, textbook-recommendation, syzygies

I want to see some examples of syzygies of projective varieties, if possible not from Eisenbud, because I know those.

Answer (score 5):

If you want examples you could try to play around with [Macaulay2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/) and compute syzygies for (almost) every possible example of varieties that you can produce.